# Get the specified record and filter laravel eloqouent

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Below is my code to get all the records where `'department'` is equal to `'admin'` (working):

```
$notification = notification::where('department', '=', "admin")->get();
```

Now I want to get all the records where `'department'` is equal to `'admin'` while excluding those records where `'department'` is equal to `'all'`. Any ideas, clues to achieve that using `laravel`'s smart eloqouent?

Comment: Try `->where('department', '<>', "all")`

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. Can your 'department' either have the value set as 'admin' or 'all'? Surely if you are getting all notifications where 'department' equals 'admin' then the 'department' value will never be 'all'.

Comment: I am confused. You already have the right notifications. What are you looking for ? Please edit your question so it makes more sense.